# find the locus of the following point

Tags: locus

let the fixed line $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}=1$ cut the coordinate axis at two points $A$ and $B$, a variable line perpendicular to the life cuts the axes at $P$ and $Q$ respectively. Find the locus of point of intersection of the lines $AQ$ and $BP$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locus is the circle having $AB$ as a diameter.

We have that either $P$ is the orthocenter of $ABQ$, or $Q$ is the orthocenter of $ABQ$, hence $AQ$ and $BP$ are orthogonal.

Comment: what is its radius??rather what is the equation of the locus, i got it as x^2 + y^2=ax+by

Comment: @ArchitNanda: if AB is a diameter, can you guess what is the radius?